# Webpack 5: "export 'default' was not found" on external module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, browser, module

I have this system of modules:

- [task](https://github.com/termsurf/task)...
- ...which requires [kink-text](https://github.com/termsurf/kink-text.js/blob/cc1671aa13fd701114f592d4382359d677e99c6d/index.ts#L1)...
- ...which requires [tint-text](https://github.com/termsurf/tint-text.js/blob/a40f13a960ae38dcd5cd69ea903b531ea15cfd4c/node.ts#L10)...
- ...which has a default export.
- Each module in this chain has `"type": "module"` in the `package.json`.

When I compile with `tsc` typescript compiler on the command-line, or [`tsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx), everything works fine. However, when I compile `task` to a standalone `task.browser.js` UMD JS file to test directly in the browser using `webpack`, it can't find my deeply nested default export on `tint-text`.

My `tsconfig.json` is this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": false,
    "noErrorTruncation": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "~/code/*": ["./code/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["code/browser.ts", "*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "host",
    "tmp",
    "code/**/node.ts",
    "code/cli/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now I bring **`webpack`** into the configuration... It messes all I had up.

I have this in my `webpack.config.mjs`:

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

export default {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
    ignored: [
      'node_modules',
      '**/node_modules',
      'code/**/node.ts',
      'code/cli/**/*.ts',
      '**/host',
    ],
  },
  entry: {
    'task.browser': './test/browser.ts',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(`./host`),
    globalObject: 'window',
    library: {
      name: 'task',
      type: 'umd',
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/code': path.resolve('./code'),
    },
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
    fallback: {
      path: path.resolve('path-browserify'),
      process: path.resolve('process/browser'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              configFile: 'tsconfig.standalone.json',
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules|host/,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

The `umd` is so I can load it directly in the browser, in an `index.html` file served from express. I don't know how to get the webpack-dev-server working yet, I tried for a few hours but it didn't work right.

```
<body>
  <script src="/task.browser.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now, when I compile my webpack with

```
webpack watch --config webpack.config.mjs
```

The final `/task.browser.js` is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _termsurf_tint_text__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default) is not a function
    at makeTextHead (index.js:28:19)
    at makeText (index.js:43:1)
    at makeKinkText (browser.js:5:20)
    at test (browser.ts:41:33)
```

That `browser.ts` is basically just doing this:

```
import { makeKinkText } from '@termsurf/kink-text'

console.error(makeKinkText({ code: 123, note: 'System error' }))
```

Going back to the links at the beginning, `task` imports [kink-text](https://github.com/termsurf/tint-text.js/blob/a40f13a960ae38dcd5cd69ea903b531ea15cfd4c/node.ts#L10) which imports [tint-text](https://github.com/termsurf/tint-text.js/blob/a40f13a960ae38dcd5cd69ea903b531ea15cfd4c/node.ts#L10), and that stack trace line `at makeTextHead (index.js:28:19)` is coming from right [here in kink-text](https://github.com/termsurf/kink-text.js/blob/cc1671aa13fd701114f592d4382359d677e99c6d/index.ts#L43):

```
import tint from '@termsurf/tint-text'

export const makeTextHead = (
  note: string,
  code: string,
  host: string,
) => {
  const list: Array<string> = []

  const R = { tone: 'red' }
  const W = { tone: 'white' }
  const H = { tone: 'blackBright' }

  // **right here** at `tint` which is undefined
  list.push(tint(`kink <`, H) + tint(`${note}`, R) + tint('>', H))
  list.push(tint(`  code <`, H) + tint(`${code}`, W) + tint(`>`, H))
  list.push(tint(`  host <`, H) + tint(`${host}`, H) + tint(`>`, H))
  return list
}
```

So why is webpack not getting this deeply nested `"type": "module"` typescript package and finding the [default export on tint-text](https://github.com/termsurf/tint-text.js/blob/a40f13a960ae38dcd5cd69ea903b531ea15cfd4c/node.ts#L10)?

**Notes**:

1. All 3 projects (task, kink-text, and tint-text) have `"type": "module"` set in `package.json`.
2. I am working in the `task` project currently.
3. Now I am trying to test `task` in the browser, so using `webpack watch` to watch the TypeScript `task` project for changes, and build a `task.browser.js` UMD output file to load in the HTML directly.
4. So the only difference is, I am using webpack now to try and build, instead of `tsc` or `tsx` TypeScript tools.
5. I am using the `ts-loader` in webpack pointing to my `tsconfig.json`, but otherwise nothing fancy.

How do I get webpack to find the default export in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part was because `export * from 'my-lib'` doesn't include the default export . Had to add `export { default } from 'my-lib'`. The [linked discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78028714/how-to-make-webpack-export-a-standalone-browser-compatible-umd-output-file-whic) is still relevant / a problem for me though.